# Is there a recommended default iptables setup?

Tags: server, iptables

I've been using ubuntu server for a while, however I have never really invested time into iptables. I was wondering if there was a recommended way to setup iptables on a basic server intall. An iptables boilerplate essentially.

Also, an explanation of all of the most commonly used ubuntu server ports would be very helpful.

Comment: Is Gufw still in development?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Gufw

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is fantastic that you are interested in iptables.

As you can see, however, there is a bit of a learning curve.

The basics are

All services listen on ports. One analogy would be an apartment complex, your ports are analogous to apartment numbers.

Common ports are

FTP - 21

SSH - 22

Apache - HTTP 80 ; HTTPS 443

You can get a complete list of ports from a google search or /etc/services

This might help as well

https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/index.html

From there, enter iptables. As a firewall, iptables is one way of limiting access.

Basically you have 3 broad options.

1. Public servers, ie apache. Here you will allow all traffic and blacklist bad acting IP (spammers)
2. Private servers, ie ssh. Here you will deny all traffic and white list authorized connections.
3. Limit. You may allow ping, but only at a certain rate.

If you are new to iptables, you may wish to start with ufw. ufw is a command line front end to iptables and is easier to learn. The syntax is very similar to iptables so it is easy to transition from ufw to iptables.

See:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo

That information should get you started. If you have a problem, feel free to ask a more specific question.

I also have an introductory page to iptables if you like. I have maintained it over the years with feedback from people new to iptables, hope it helps.

http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/iptables

Comment: `/etc/ports`? You mean `/etc/services`?

Comment: sorry about that.

Comment: no need to be sorry :) Your posts, blog and other resources have always been a great help to me. Thanks for all that.

Comment: Hmm, is there any disadvantage to using ufw for basic setup?

Comment: The only disadvantages I can think of would be personal preferences, some people may prefer alternate tools (alternate graphical tools, iptables) or have preferred options (DROP vs REJECT). The other "disadvantage" would be that if you did wish to run a service (ssh, samba, nfs, VNC) you would then need to open the port in your firewall.

Answer (score 4):

The recommended way (for beginners) is to enable ufw which in turn automatically sets up basic `iptables` rules for you:

```
sudo ufw enable
```

Basically this will block all unsolicited packets (for the full list of rules that are set up this way see `sudo iptables -L`).

To be able to connect to the server, you will have to allow a few ports, for instance

```
sudo ufw allow 22/tcp
```

to allow `ssh` etc.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend that you also add protection against some scan types and unusual (possibly malicious) tcp settings:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE  -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,PSH,URG -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,RST,ACK,URG -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -j DROP
-A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
```

(Via [hideandhack.com](http://www.hideandhack.com/).)